# How to programmatically simulate arrow key presses in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, keypress

I want to make my JFX application simulate arrow key presses (when they are registered in a TextField), but I can't figure out how to send anything other than Strings or bytes.

I'm imagining something like this:

```
static EventHandler<KeyEvent> KEY() {
    E = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.UP)) {
                try {
                    //someObject.SimulateKeyPress(KeyCode.UP);

                    //OR

                    //coolObject.SendKey((char)KEY_UPKEY));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    //Teleport goats
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return E;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the class [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

```
 try {
    Robot r = new Robot();
    //there are other methods such as positioning mouse and mouseclicks etc.
    r.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_UP);
    r.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_UP);
 } catch (AWTException e) {
    //Teleport penguins  
 }
```

Comment: This simulates keypresses in whatever is currently focused application, not necessarily related to javafx or jvm process at all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate the type Robot.
You should rather do :

```
  Robot robot = com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
```

Comment: Also be aware that from Java 9 onwards, `com.sun` APIs may not be visible to application programmers using the JDK.

Comment: I don't know where you got this from, but you can absolutely instantiate `Robot`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#Robot--

Comment: Lion is referring to a different robot Michael.  Perhaps the awt robot is an alternative to the glass robot in this case Lion (I don't know enough about robots to say for sure).

Comment: How can "they" decide to remove access to FXRobot without providing an alternative?!?!?!? I don't understand this BLATANT disregard?