# Call event handler

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a TabPane with test button which calls this code:

```
Button bt1 = new Button("Select");

        bt1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent event)
            {
                TreeClass.getConnectedAgentsMap();

                TreePane.getTreeView().getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(3);   

            }
        });
```

This code selects TreeNode into TreeView:

```
cell.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent me) ->
                {
                    if (!cell.isEmpty())
                    {
                        /// some action
                    }
                });
```

As you can see this event is triggered when mouse selects tree row.
I tried to call the tree cell action with this code:

```
cell.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)
                    {
                        /// Some Action

                    }
                });
```

But it's not the proper way to use it because several times new Tab is opened. Is there a way when I click the button to call action event?

Comment: Please can you explain what you want done, do you want to fire an click event where there was none?

Comment: I want to fire mouse click event on the tree. First I want to select the three node the I want to simulate mouse click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258995/how-to-programmatically-simulate-arrow-key-presses-in-java-fx/24259248#24259248

Comment: Are you sure? In this example awt is used? Can you show me some quick example with JavaFX 8?

Comment: I have posted the example, I hope it works. If you need further help just comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Point2D windowCoord = new Point2D(SCENE.getWindow().getX(), SCENE.getWindow().getY());
final Point2D sceneCoord = new Point2D(SCENE.getX(), Main.getStage().getScene().getY());
final Point2D nodeCoord = MYCONTROL.localToScene(0.0, 0.0);

final double x = Math.round(windowCoord.getX() + sceneCoord.getX() + nodeCoord.getX());
final double y = Math.round(windowCoord.getY() + sceneCoord.getY() + nodeCoord.getY());
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(new Double(x).intValue()+1, new Double(y).intValue());
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
} catch (AWTException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Some of the code is borrowed from [this website](http://blog.crisp.se/2012/08/29/perlundholm/window-scene-and-node-coordinates-in-javafx).